# Java - Sound Effects Doesn't Play

Tags: java, file, url, audio, if-statement

I have a program which plays audio but when I need to play a different audio file it does play (and there is no mistake in the location/spelling ).

```
    if ((getCoordinatesOfDuplicates() == null) && (getEmptyCellsCount() == 0)) {

        try {
            java.applet.AudioClip clip =
                    java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(
                    new java.net.URL("file:src//audio/applause2.wav"));

            clip.play();
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException murle) {
            System.out.println(murle);
        }
        System.out.println("Well Done");

    } else  {
        try {
            java.applet.AudioClip clip =
                    java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(
                    new java.net.URL("file:src//audio/shutoff.wav"));

            clip.play();
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException murle) {
            System.out.println(murle);
        }
        System.out.println("You did something wrong in the puzzle");

    }
```

The Applause plays fine but the shutoff doesn't play even though the code is the exactly the same and the "You did something wrong in the puzzle" shows up.

Any Ideas?

Comment: And you get no other messages?
Have you tried loading the "shutoff.wav" in the first block insted, and virce versa? Just to rule that out :)

Comment: Yes I have and it doesn't work

Comment: So by "dosen't work" you mean that the last block still dosen't work - but the first block does (no matter what soud)?
Have you tried printing something out before and after the code in the last try-block?

Comment: Both blocks work but only when the applause2.wav effect is played. All other audio files don't work, whether you put it in the first or second block.

Comment: What happens if you totally omits the first try-block? :)

Comment: I've tried but the applause2.wav works whereas all other audio files don't play. :D

Comment: That is truly odd. Write a whole new (simple, just a main method) program and try the play function there! :D

Comment: Don't worry bro, I managed to find it out. The wav files were corrupted when I downloaded them.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the all the audio files were corrupted, with the exception of `applause2.wav`. Getting the non-corrupted files resolved the issue.